# Can you add rotation to the current css values using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

OK lets say for example I have 3 square divs on a page, one of them is rotated at -20 degrees, one at -10 degrees and one at 10 degrees. When I hover over them I would like them to rotate by + 10 degrees.

In the CSS it appears one can only set the position the shape will finish on, so if I put a value of 10 degrees the first shape would be moving 30 degrees while the last wouldn't move at all.

Is there a way of using jQuery where I can tell it to rotate 10 degrees from its current position? I don't know if theres any way of putting those css values into jQuery, so I can then add 10 and re-output as a rotate function.

Here's the CSS as requested...

```
.photo {

-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;

position: absolute;

}

.photo:hover {
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(10deg);
-o-transform:rotate(10deg);
}

.image-1 {
-webkit-transform:rotate(-20deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-20deg);
-o-transform:rotate(-20deg);

top: 60px;
left: 60px;
width: 260px;
height: 185px;

}

.image-2 {
-webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-10deg);
-o-transform:rotate(-10deg);

top: 60px;
left: 320px;
width: 280px;
height: 210px;

}

.image-3 {
-webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(10deg);
-o-transform:rotate(10deg);

top: 60px;
left: 600px;
width: 280px;
height: 185px;

}
```

Here is what I've got now following on from the first recieved answer

```
    var angle1 = 10;
var angle2 = 0;
var angle3 = -10;

$('.image-1').css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle1+'deg)');
$('.image-2').css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle2+'deg)');
$('.image-3').css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle3+'deg)'); 

$('.image-1').mouseover(function(){
angle1b = angle1 + 5;
$(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle1b+'deg)');
});
$('.image-1').mouseout(function(){
$(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle1+'deg)');
});

$('.image-2').mouseover(function(){
angle2b = angle2 + 5;
$(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle2b+'deg)');
});
$('.image-2').mouseout(function(){
$(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle2+'deg)');
});

$('.image-3').mouseover(function(){
angle3b = angle3 + 5;
$(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle3b+'deg)');
});
$('.image-3').mouseout(function(){
$(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle3+'deg)');
});
```

... I realise this is quite bulky and I could probably use a for? loop to do the same function for each image-1, image-2 etc. I had a quick go but I'm not too familiar with javascript. My guess is its something to do with 'image'+i for each but I can't figure it out. If anyone could help with that it would be much appreciated. Then all I'd have to change were the initial variables.

Comment: well a helping starting point would be to post the code you have showing the 3 divs and the initial CSS rotation

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick sketch:

```
var angle1 = -20;
var angle2 = -10;
var angle3 = 10;

$('.image-1').click(function(){
    angle1 = angle1 + 10;
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+angle1+'deg)');
});
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I'm using now, check out my updated question. Don't suppose you have any idea how to shorten this as described? Thanks

Comment: The code you post seems like you are just switching between two states and additionaly, you are doing that by hover, so both can be done purely by css.
Alternatively, you can take use of both an id and a class. Class will define the logic script and by Id you can decide which variable to use

Comment: This is true, but my actual project has much more than 3 divs, so if I could use javascript and use a for loop to run through each image it would be considerably less code. See the bottom of my question for what I mean. I can't quite figure it out

Comment: Bulky css might still be better than using JS, but thats just my opinion. You can use css preprocessor, where you can generate css with preprocessor. Or you can generate it yourself with any server side language - PHP, Ruby, Node.js etc. I may add some example code later when I have more time.

Answer (score 2):

As you know the original angles, you can achieve this with pure CSS, using ':hover'. You just need to manually set the angle for each `image-n` class to 10 deg more than the unhovered one, e.g. `.image-1` has `transform:rotate(-20deg);` so set `.image-1:hover` to `transform:rotate(-10deg);`.

You can also add the transition to the unhovered versions so you get a nice animation when you mouseout.

I tried to do something more dynamic with jQuery as you suggested, but the way the transition css is stored is not just `-10deg`, but as a matrix, so this would be much harder to do.

Here's the updated CSS with a working snippet. The only other changes I made to this are adding a background-color for clarity and adding the non-vendor-specific `transition` CSS:

```css
.photo {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
}

.photo:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(10deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(10deg);
}

.image-1 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    transform:rotate(-20deg);
    top: 60px;
    left: 60px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 185px;
    background-color:red;
}

.image-2 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    transform:rotate(-10deg);
    top: 60px;
    left: 320px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 210px;
    background-color:green;
}

.image-3 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(10deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(10deg);
    transform:rotate(10deg);
    top: 60px;
    left: 600px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 185px;
    background-color:blue;
}

/* apply a transition to all images for when you come off the hover */
.image-1, .image-2, .image-3 {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

/* for each image set the hover angle to 10 more than the previous  */

.image-1:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    transform:rotate(-10deg);
}

.image-2:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0);
    -moz-transform:rotate(0);
    -o-transform:rotate(0);
    transform:rotate(0);
}

.image-3:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(20deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(20deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(20deg);
    transform:rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="a1" class="image-1">Image 1</div>
<div id="a2" class="image-2">Image 2</div>
<div id="a3" class="image-3">Image 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats basically how I had it already, I was just seeing if there was a more concise way of doing it. Since the first answer I got I've converted those rotations to jQuery. Its about the same amount of code, however in jQuery I can't put the non vendor specific versions can I? I may switch back. Thanks for the answer